# Two matches in sed or grep

Tags: sed, grep

I am using grep to capture the id and name separately in the following two commands:

```
echo "id=\"12345678_name\">myname</td>" | grep -oP "(?<=id=\\).*?(?=_name)"
echo "id=\"12345678_name\">myname</td>" | grep -oP "(?<=name).*?(?=<\/td)"
```

How can I do the whole thing in a single grep or sed command? I need to following output:

```
12345678, myname
```

I'm doing this on the command line and in a batch file in Windows (6.2.9200) using GNU Sed version 4.2.1.

Comment: That first one does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "id=\"12345678_name\">myname</td>" | sed -re 's~id=\"([0-9]+)_name\">([^<]+)</td>~\1, \2~g'
```

I used a `sed` search and replace. Basically the search string is the whole line with pattern in parenthesis for the bit we want to extract, then the replacement string.

search for: `id=\"([0-9]+)_name\">([^<]+)</td>`

replace with: `\1, \2`

`\1` is first pattern in `()`, one or more digits.

`\2` is second pattern in `()`, anything but a `<`

Both patterns are in a context, so will find correct text. However this search string is very rigid about the context.

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work in the command prompt in Windows. Is the syntax a lot different from Unix?

Comment: Can you add, to question, the operating system, shell, and tools you are using.

Comment: @user2146441 yes Microsoft windows can be a lot different to Unix, the differences depend on which Unix emulation system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'id=\"12345678_name\">myname</td>' |sed -r 's#id=\\"([[:digit:]]+)[^>]+>([[:alpha:]]+)</td>#\1, \2#g'
```